# Javascript: I'm trying to manipulate HTML by adding a class to an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add .hidden to 2 classes. However after running the code I can't get the if statement to check changed status in the website once a change was made. OVERALL GOAL: Once clicked outside of Modal I want Modal to close.

```
const modalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.show-modal');

const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');

const closeModal = document.querySelector('.close-modal');

const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');

const body = document.body;
    for (let i = 0; i < modalButtons.length; i++) {
      modalButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        modal.classList.remove('hidden');
        overlay.classList.remove('hidden');
      });
    if (!modal.classList.contains('hidden')) {
        modal.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
          if (modal.contains(e.target)) {
          } else {
            modal.classList.add('hidden');
            overlay.classList.add('hidden');
          }
        });
      } 
    }
```

// HTML FILE BELOW

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Modal window</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="show-modal">Show modal 1</button>
    <button class="show-modal">Show modal 2</button>
    <button class="show-modal">Show modal 3</button>

    <div class="modal hidden">
      <button class="close-modal">&times;</button>
      <h1>I'm a modal window </h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
        veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
        commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
        occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
        mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay hidden"></div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `if` condition is running for every single `modalButton` iteration. Was that intended? looks like the same thing happens over and over again...attaching the same event listener to the `modal`

Comment: @D.B.K Yes this was since I have 3 different show modal buttons

Comment: no, I mean, you have ONE modal, right? and your for loop runs 3 times, because you have 3 showModalButtons. Now for each iteration , the SAME modal is getting the SAME event listener attached. Was that intended?

Comment: Can you show us your HTML structure. How many elements with class modal do you have?

Comment: @D.B.K Yes if I do it once so only the first modal button will work

Comment: @AHaworth Yes let me know your thoughts

Comment: If I add document.addEventListener... then it will simply not make the modalButtons catch click since the global click will proceed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your html code it's hard to understand what your code supposed to do. So I'd suggest instead of applying css class to the modal/overlay itself, apply it to body instead, this way you'll have a more control how other elements behave when modal is opened, for example you can blur everything under the overlay:

```js
const modalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.show-modal');

const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');

const closeModal = document.querySelector('.close-modal');

const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');

const body = document.body;
for (let i = 0; i < modalButtons.length; i++) {
  modalButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    document.body.classList.add('popup');
    modal.querySelector(".body").title = e.target.textContent;
  });
};
modal.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target === overlay || e.target === closeModal) {
    document.body.classList.remove('popup');
  }
});
```

```css
body:not(.popup) > .modal
{
  display: none;
}

/* popup is opened */
body.popup > :not(.modal)
{
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
.modal
{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
}

.modal > .content {
  z-index: 999;
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  padding-top: 1.5em;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
}

.modal .body:after
{
  content: " opened by: " attr(title);
}

.modal .close-modal
{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="show-modal">click 1</button>
  <button class="show-modal">click 2</button>
  <button class="show-modal">click 3</button>
</div>

<div class="modal">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="body">
      this is modal popup
    </div>
    <button class="close-modal">close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @vanowm I am trying to understand how to click outside of an element in order to close it as it seems to not work. Your code is correct and I have a format of this too.

Comment: "the outside" is equal to overlay. In your code your overlay is not part of the modal, therefore you'd need register 2 separate listeners on overlay and close button. If you'd place it inside modal, you'd need only one listener on modal itself, and from there you just need to check which element was clicked on as you can see it in my example

Comment: I understand so I was able to change my code with overlay this works well thanks! What if I did not have an overlay or is this something that is always necessary to add?

Comment: It's easier with overlay, plus it doesn't have to be visible.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this may be a possible solution to your problem(Check the JS):

```js
const modalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.show-modal');

const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');

const closeModal = document.querySelector('.close-modal');

const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');

const body = document.body;
    for (let i = 0; i < modalButtons.length; i++) {
      modalButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        modal.classList.remove('hidden');
        overlay.classList.remove('hidden');
        document.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
          let targetEl = evt.target; // clicked element 
          if(targetEl == overlay){//check to see if the overlay has been clicked then close the modal.
        modal.classList.add("hidden");
        overlay.classList.add("hidden");
        }         
      });
      });      
     /*if (!modal.classList.contains('hidden')) {
        modal.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
          if (modal.contains(e.target)) {
          } else {
            modal.classList.add('hidden');
            overlay.classList.add('hidden');
        }
      });
      }*/
    }
```

```css
.overlay{
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
  width:50vw;
  height:50vh;
}

.hidden{
  opacity:0;
}

body{
  background-color:black;
}

.modal{
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  border:1px solid black;
  background:white;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="overlay hidden">Your overlay(click to close)
    <img class="modal hidden center" alt="your modal">
  </div>
  <button class="show-modal">Show modal</button>
  <button class="show-modal">Show modal</button>
  <button class="show-modal">Show modal</button>
</body>
```

This is achieved using a listener to check where the click is launched. You could modify this to work for multiple modals and for when different elements are clicked(just add to the conditional if when checking to see which target was selected, then hide the modal).

Comment: Thanks, however Im trying to see if this would work without an overlay HTML how to do this? I thought my code with an if-else statement would use the else statement however if the initial 'if'= body then the open modal wont work and if its an initial 'if' with modal click and else is to click outside that target then it wont capture the click. Wanted to see if theres a solution for that or if Overlay is always necassary

Comment: You can check if the target is not equal to the modal. Change the if to !=modal then anything that isn't the modal will hide it(you'll have to add another condition to check if the button was clicked (!=button[i]), otherwise, anytime you try to open the modal it will immediately trigger the hide). You don't need the overlay to close it, but when using a click to any other part of the document you'll need to make sure the button is excluded from closing the modal. eg.' if(targetEl != modal && targetEl!=modalButtons[i])'